# How to perform NIAP certification for a software using OpenSSL?

Tags: openssl, certificate

We wish to our certify our software to be NIAP certified.

As described in the following links ([link1](https://www.openssl.org/blog/blog/2019/11/07/3.0-update/), [link2](https://www.openssl.org/docs/fips.html)) it seems like OpenSSL is not NIAP certified anymore.

Obviously replacing all the usages of OpenSSL in our code is a long and complex task and I'm really not sure this is the right path to go.
Anyone is familiar with other alternatives rather just removing all the OpenSSL instances?

Thanks,
Nir.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as NIAP certified openssl. you can use vanilla openssl as long as it fulfills self-test directives dictated by your protection profile. There are some opensource alternatives which you could rely on ( some premium ) by ubuntu and redhat.

If you are inquiring about fips certification which is different from NIAP compliance, current only options are openssl 1.0.2 and it's fips module or wait for openssl 3.0 to be fips compliant in the coming year( 2022).